# Why do these two instructions have the same opcode?

Tags: assembly, x86

I was doing some assembly programming (Actually writing an assembler) and I noticed that `MOV EBX, <something>` and `MOV BX, <something>` have the same opcode `0xBB`! Why is that and how does the processor differentiate between the two? Does it differentiate based on the size of the second operand? And is this the reason why the 80386 instruction set is said to be complicated?

Comment: Look at the *entire* instruction generated. The operands may be encoded separately - ie. look at http://ref.x86asm.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default operand size is defined by the current operating mode, and you can toggle using a `0x66` prefix. When running in 32 bit mode `0xBB` is a 32 bit move, and `0x66 0xBB` is 16 bit. In 16 bit mode, the situation is reversed.

In 32 bit mode:

```
66 BB 34 12               mov bx, 0x1234
BB 78 56 34 12            mov ebx, 0x12345678
```

In 16 bit mode:

```
BB 34 12                  mov bx, 0x1234
66 BB 78 56 34 12         mov ebx, 0x12345678
```

Comment: [This opcode chart](http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#mov) clearly says that   the opcode for `MOV BX,<immediate value>` is `0xBB` and for  `MOV AX,<immediate value>` is `0xB8`. You can check.

Comment: Yeah, true. That's the `mov bx, immediate`. What I listed is the `mov bx, r/m`. The `0x66` logic applies to both just the same though.